# v11.10 System settings is displaying 41 copies of every app

Tags: 11.10

I just switched from 11.04 to 11.10 on Monday (when support for 11.04 ended), and now the system settings app takes forever to come up, and when it does, there are 41 copies of all the apps. 41 "Appearence", 41 "Keyboard Layout", 41 copies of everything.

This is highly strange. I'm not the type to go messing with things I am unfamiliar with, and I am not incompetent with ubuntu. I have no idea how this happened, and I am wondering if anyone else has ever seen such a thing, or can give me a clue as to where to look for a solution.

It's not a "problem" as of yet, but it certainly indicates a problem sooner or later.